# MYSQL: Filtering by Column with array value

Tags: mysql

I would like to ask how to filter a table by column with array value, I have a column "categories" that can have a value like `[1,2,3]` now I want to filter the table with that table like `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CATEGORIES = 2`,

I also tried `LIKE` but it seems like it is not the proper way to do it, any opinions and suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the [SQL IN Operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)?

Comment: @rmjoia yes sir but no luck

Comment: So the `categories` column value is "1,2,3" or "[1,2,3]"?

Comment: @Neodan its [1,2,3] since it is an array

Comment: @Hannyson it's not an array, it's just a text. It's mean that your DB schema is realy bad (-;

Comment: @Neodan maybe sir, it's a string sir but in a form of array, the datatype of it is varchar but what i am storing inside is an array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not recommended way to store comma separated values in Column which needs to be filtered for queries.

You can use `normalization` and introduce relationship tables for categories and `category_ids` to be stored in different tables, then you can use `join` and `where` clause to achieve your results.

Comment: Will follow your advise then Sir Thank you.